# HTML not rendering properly in firefox (working great in chrome)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, devextreme

If you try to open [this link](http://46.101.134.53:3000/#/collections/Products) in google chrome you can see in a few seconds the rows appear in the table. (I am using devextreme's dxDataGrid and angularjs) But if you open the same thing in the firefox browser, the rows never appear, I inspected the elements from the development tools of firefox, I can see the HTML of rows there but I cannot see them in the browser, how is this possible? Please help me!

Comment: As I can see, you use angularjs v.1.4.0, but according this [article](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/3rd-Party_Libraries_and_Frameworks_Integration/?version=14_2#Data_Binding_and_SPA_Frameworks) you can use only angularjs v.1.2.X or 1.3.X Also, I suggest you use the `dx-data-grid` directive from [documentation](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/?version=14_2) instead of your custom `dxgrid` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect this element:

```
<div class="dx-datagrid-rowsview dx-datagrid-nowrap dx-scrollable dx-scrollable-customizable-scrollbars dx-scrollable-both dx-scrollable-simulated dx-visibility-change-handler" style="display: block; height: 0px;" tabindex="0">
```

If you delete `height: 0px` the rows will appear.